# What is the difference between just, almost and quite?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I have a problem understanding the use of these adjectives: just, almost and quite. 
What is the difference between them? What is the fine line that separate uses of these adjectives?

Comment: There is no "fine line"; it's more like a "fuzzy gray area". Plus, it's very context dependent. These three words can be used in quite a few ways, so it's almost impossible to provide a brief rule that covers just about every usage. It might help if you edited your question to provide a sample context that's confusing you, or paste in the definitions you've read that indicate an overlap.